# Django : how to display actual objects in admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-orm

I have a model defination as follows:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    """Model class to record Artist"""
    artist_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    artist_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    # similar relationship is defined.
    related_to = models.ManyToManyField("self", null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.artist_name
```

when i use 'delete' admin action for the artists from django' admin panel i get:

```
Artist: trojan

    From_artist-to_artist relationship: Artist_related_to object
    From_artist-to_artist relationship: Artist_related_to object
    From_artist-to_artist relationship: Artist_related_to object
    From_artist-to_artist relationship: Artist_related_to object

Artist: betty

    From_artist-to_artist relationship: Artist_related_to object
    From_artist-to_artist relationship: Artist_related_to object
```

how do i get the actual relations that i am warned during delete?

in other words how to humanize 'Artist_related_to object' to reflect actual artist name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing in the admin delete question are instances of the ManyToMany bridge model that Django transparently creates for you.

If you want to change their `__unicode__` representation you will have to define your own bridge model and set the the `ManyToManyField` to use it with the [through parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through).

Example:

```
class ArtistRelationship(models.Model):
    from_artist = models.ForeignKey('Artist')
    to_artist = models.ForeignKey('Artist')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s - %s" % (self.from_artist.name, self.to_artist.name)


class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # ... more fields ...
    related_to = models.ManyToManyField("self", null=True, blank=True,
                                        through=ArtistRelationship)
```

Answer (score -2):

The return must be a string instead of a CharField, try this: `return u"%s" % (self.artist_name, )`

Comment: i do not think u tried what i gave on the question, try and then reply it does not work the way u picture.